# IOS Simple Messaging client, presence and typing

Tags: ios, socket.io, messaging

I'm considering adding a messaging feature to an iphone app.  The idea being that given a user-based IOS app, a user may have a list of other users.  He may then want to send one a message. A straight network call could accomplish this, but it misses a couple pieces:

1) The ability for a logged in user to "listen" for incoming messages without necessarily polling the server every few seconds.  Does IOS support an open socket connection for listening somehow?

2) The ability for the server to detect presence of users (when they are logged in, active and listening;  and immediately if they connect/disconnect)

3) the ability to detect typing, if possible

I've heard this can be achieved in javascript apps with socket.io libs, and wondering what equivalent tools exist in IOS natively?  Or should a webview with JS be attempted?

**EDIT:**

Push notifications will likely be leveraged for offline use, but am not sure they can be a substitute for all the real time interaction.

**EDIT2:**

Found this SocketIO tool for IOS, but have no experience with this.  It is a possibility though.
https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc

Answer (score 1):

For number one you should look at this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1
It uses pushnotifications to detect incoming messages.

the other two parts are probably timing, just say a user is active for 2 min since their last activity. And every time they use something in the app or poll the server you update the time and make them active for another two minutes or so.

And you can detect typing if something is typed into the textfield. `UITextField` has a onChanged method. You could also start a timer to detect changes between a certain amount of time. So it doesn't say typing if someone just left their textfield filled but didn't send the message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Push notifications will be leveraged of course, but mainly for offline usage.  If the user is sitting in a message window, I'm not sure it serves the same purpose as realtime updates.  The 2nd could work, though it leaves holes open for the unknown, of whether the user is still there or not.

Comment: Pushnotification will give you a trigger to poll the server. You could also let the server know when a users closes the app. There is a method `applicationWillEnterBackground`